# MATLAB: Using the 'resubstitution' option in sequentialfs

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I'm new to MATLAB and trying to implement sequentialfs to identify the best subsets to fit a linear regression. I've read through the online documentation but am finding it difficult to understand.

I have  set of training data and would like to use the 'resubstitution' option to apply this as test data as well.

x_train is a matrix with 67 rows and 8 columns.
y_train has 67 rows and 1 column.

Could somebody please check why this code doesn't work?

```
x_train = std_pros_pred_full;
y_train = pros_resp;

fun_RSS = @RSS_check;
inmodel = sequentialfs(fun_RSS,x_train,y_train,'resubstitution');
```

The function RSS_check performs a linear regression calculation and outputs the sum of squared errors. It's defined (externally) like this:

```
function RSS_out = RSS_check(X,Y)

lin1 = X'*X;
lin2 = X'*Y;
lin_coef = (lin1^-1)*lin2; 
lin_fit = X*lin_coef;

row_count = size(Y,1);
RSS_out = 0;

for q = 1:row_count
  pred_diff = lin_fit(q,1) - Y(q,1);
  RSS_out =RSS_out + pred_diff^2;
end
```

The error message is: 
Error using sequentialfs (line 212)
Wrong number of arguments.

When trying different options, I've also had errors concerning the number of inputs and outputs to the function. A lot of examples I've seen reference separate matrices of test data (giving 4 inputs), but I thought that would be unnecessary with the 'resubstitution' option.

Comment: `RSS_check` must define four inputs according to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/sequentialfs.html): `criterion = fun(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST,ytest)`

Comment: Thanks for the response Troy. I've read through that documentation several times but I'm finding it unclear. In this example (down the page), they only have 2 input variables:
    
    '[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,X,y,'cv',c,'options',opts)'

Further up they have the line with both training and test data, but I'm not sure how I can apply that as I want to base the regression on training data only.

I think the issue might be the function as it's set up differently to any examples I've seen, but not sure how else to do this based on least squares.

Comment: In that example, the input function `fun` is defined as an anonymous functions of four variables: `fun = @(XT,yT,Xt,yt) ...`.

Comment: True - but what do you think the 4 variables should be if you're using the 'resubstitution' option? Because in that case you don't have separate test and training data (if I've understood correctly).
Sorry if this is just showing my ignorance. I have been through absolutely every example I can find online, but I just can't see anything applicable to my situation. They all seem to have very simple, locally defined functions with separate training and test data, which is different to the problem I've been given.

Comment: From the documentation: "When the value is `'resubstitution'`, the original data are passed to `fun` as both the training and test data to compute the criterion."  And to be honest, I'm not a Machine Learning person at all, but the core of the error stems from `fun` being defined with the "Wrong number of arguments".  For clarity, you could define `fun` thusly: `fun_RSS = @(x,y,varargin) RSS_check(x,y);`.

Comment: Thanks Troy - that did help! I used your line to define the function and also changed the sequentialfs line to this:

'inmodel = sequentialfs(fun_RSS,x_train,y_train,'cv','resubstitution')'

I had tried that same line before and it hadn't worked, but with the function defined properly it works :)

Thanks again!